# Cancelling an Apple subscription

Tags: accounts

I no longer own any Apple devices. No iMacs, no iPhones, no iPads.

However I am still being charged $15/month for my HBO Now subscription because I chose to sign up to that through Apple Pay back when I did have Apple devices.

However I no longer see any way to cancel my HBO subscription without owning any Apple devices, as I don't see any way to manage subscriptions online.

Is there any way to cancel my subscription without owning an Apple device?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can unsubscribe from a PC:

Make sure iTunes is installed, then open it up. From the menu Account choose View Account and sign in with your Apple-ID.

Now select View Account again, and in the Settings section click “Manage” besides Subscriptions.

From the list of subscriptions, press Edit for the HBO subscription you want to cancel. Now select that you want to Cancel, and confirm your cancellation.

An alternative option is to call Apple and let them help you cancel the subscription.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm installing iTunes on windows then (which almost never ends well)

Comment: @MarkHenderson  So use a mac...will work the same...

Comment: I dont have a Mac. If I did this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @MarkHenderson the answer does not say you have to “own” either... borrow one or go to an internet cafe...